# ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am receiving this error message when i try to execute the following code.

```
ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction
```

Can anyone advice where the problem is? I guess the root of the problem is the part where i try to execute a stored procedure.

The stored procedure is creates its own transaction when execute

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                SqlTransaction transaction;

                // Start a local transaction.
                transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("createOrder");

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO rand_resupply_order (study_id, centre_id, date_created, created_by) " +
                        "VALUES (@study_id, @centre_id, @date_created, @created_by) SET @order_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

                    command.Parameters.Add("@study_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = study_id;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@centre_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = centre_id;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@date_created", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@created_by", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

                    SqlParameter order_id = new SqlParameter("@order_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    //study_name.Value = 
                    order_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(order_id);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Parameters.Clear();

                    //loop resupply list 
                    for (int i = 0; i < resupplyList.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateOrder", conn);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@study_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = study_id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@centre_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = centre_id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@created_by", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = resupplyList[i].Quantity;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@centre_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = centre_id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@depot_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = depot_id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@treatment_code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = centre_id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)order_id.Value;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "error");
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "error");
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Dispose();
                        }

                    }

                    return (int)order_id.Value;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "error");
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                    transaction.Commit();

                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    command.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: Minor point - you shouldn't try to commit in the `finally` - that should, instead, be in the `try`, after your operation

Comment: might be a bit old, but can you please confirm that my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 13):

when using transaction, you should use it everywhere.

```
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
```

Comment: does it matter when the stored procedures itself contains its own transaction?

Comment: so the question is how can i achieve running a transaction that will call a stored procedure with its own transaction :(

Comment: you do not need to do anything specific, just let .net do it's job, try above code and hopefully all will be good :)

Answer (score 2):

using Connection String transaction not popular so far.you can delete every things that related to `SqlTransaction` and then wrap your code with [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: Be very careful with TransactionScope.  It seems quite nice when it works.  But I have found it to be very fragile when targeting non-local SQL servers.  You need things to be setup "just right".